# Death Note no Python - Loop Sentinel of Death

Tags: python

Estou com uma dúvida no meu código do **Death Note** onde não consigo **criar um loop para pedir se o usuário do caderno deseja matar mais alguém** e o código deve ser encerrado quando o usuário não quiser mais matar alguém. Alguém ai me dá uma força juro que não escrevo o nome no **Death Note**.

**Observação**: No anime **Light Yagami quando não define a morte da pessoa esse pessoa morre automaticamente da parada cardíaca** e no `if morte == ' '` **não entra nessa condição**, qual seria o problema?

```
usuario = str (input("Digite o nome do usuário do caderno: "))
print ("Bem vindo ao Death Note {}".format(usuario))
print ("Deseja matar alguém? ")
resposta = str (input("S - Sim | N - Não: "))
if resposta == 'S' or resposta == 's':
    nome = str (input("Digite o nome da vítima: "))
    morte = str (input("Digite a causa da morte: "))
    if morte == ' ': # Não funciona essa condição
        print ("O nome da vítima é {}".format(nome))
        print ("E morreu de uma parada cardíaca!")
    else:
        print ("O nome da vítima é {}".format(nome))
        print ("Causa da morte: {}".format(morte))

print ("Deseja matar mais alguém {}?".format(usuario))    '''
outramorte = str (input("S - Sim | N - Não: "))      Loop sentinela
                                                          '''
else:
    print ("{} volte quando quiser para limpar o mundo!!!".format(usuario))
```

Comment: Primeiro acho que a checagem do suicídio é `nome == usuario`, Sabendo disso você pode solucionar o **Obs 2** colocando um `if` antes do print verificando se o `nome!=usuario` assim ele só da `print` se o ultimo nome for diferente, uma outra solução e você criar uma outra variável para guardar o tipo da última morte, outra coisa: quando for suicidio talvez você tenha que tambem que pular o `resposta = (input...` e colocar como `N`  =)

Comment: @IcaroMartins Fiquei um pouco perdido

Comment: Ola @alex, acredito que o **problema original** (*Death Note no Python - Loop Sentinel of Death*) foi solucionado por uma das respostas abaixo. Note que as ultimas edições fizeram as respostas perderem o contexto, o ideal agora seria você reverter a(s) edição(ões) (*aceitar a resposta que te ajudou no problema original*) e criar uma nova pergunta e se precisar adicionar contexto a nova pergunta adicionar um link para esta. =D

Comment: Eu ainda não entendi a solução mesmo com as respostas abaixo, algumas delas realmente me ajudaram em alguns detalhes do meu código mas o foco dos problemas que eu editei ainda não porque de repente eu quis implementar o códigos pensando em algumas que fizessem sentido igual ao Death Note no anime.

Comment: Ou seja pensei em algumas melhorias no código e acabei não entendendo como faz essas melhorias na codificação.

Comment: Reverti sua postagem pois ela invalida as respostas dadas. Queira dar uma lida em [tour] e [help] para entender melhor o modelo do site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O seu código não possui um loop, apenas uma verificação com if. Para que ele retorne a si mesmo, devemos aplicar um loop. Mais precisamente um laço while. O laço `while` é um tipo de laço de repetição que se repete até que a dada condição seja falsa.

Mas antes de aplicarmos, devemos nos atentar à um detalhe da sua pergunta:

> Observação: No anime Light Yagami quando não define a morte da pessoa esse pessoa morre automaticamente da parada cardíaca e no `if morte == ' '` não entra nessa condição, qual seria o problema?

Esse `if morte == ' '` não verifica se a string está vazia, mas se a pessoa inseriu um espaço, para corrigir isso apenas digite `if morte == ''` no lugar.

Além disso, caso estejamos tratando aqui do Python 3.x (o que é altamente recomendável de se usar) não é necessário adicionar estes `str()` uma vez que o retorno do input do Python 3.x já é do tipo string. Além de tornar mais legível o código, diminui o uso de processamento. E se for Python 2, temos a função `raw_input()` como a correta neste caso.

### Como posso agora inserir o laço while?

Para implementar o laço while, basta renomearmos `if` para `while` uma vez que queremos que o código retorne novamente àquele ponto de partida. Uma vez feito isso, renomeamos a variável *outramorte* para *resposta*, assim quando retornar para a verificação do while (`resposta == 'S' or resposta == 's'`) o valor da *resposta* já vai ter mudado.

Ou seja, caso a resposta seja diferente de "S" ou "s", ele vai simplesmente parar o loop e executar a próxima linha, que é o tchauzinho pra galera.

Este seria o código final:

```py
usuario = input("Digite o nome do usuário do caderno: ")
print ("Bem vindo ao Death Note {}".format(usuario))
print ("Deseja matar alguém? ")
resposta = input("S - Sim: N - Não: ")
while resposta == 'S' or resposta == 's':
    nome = input("Digite o nome da vítima: ")
    morte = input("Digite a causa da morte: ")
    if morte == '':
        print ("O nome da vítima é {}".format(nome))
        print ("E morreu de uma parada cardíaca!")
    else:
        print ("O nome da vítima é {}".format(nome))
        print ("Causa da morte: {}".format(morte))

    print ("Deseja matar mais alguém {}?".format(usuario))
    resposta = input("S - Sim: N - Não: ")

print ("{} volte quando quiser para limpar o mundo!!!".format(usuario))
```

---

A propósito, esse anime é excelente.

Comment: Vou dar uma implementada no código inserindo uma condição que caso o usuário insira o próprio nome ele comete suicídio e o código termina, eu espero que dê certo.

Comment: Minha implementação deu certo, só que quando cai nas **duas condições de suicídio (quando coloca o próprio nome e a causa da morte e quando coloca o próprio nome e não justifica a causa da morte)** também aparece o ```print ("{} volte quando quiser para limpar o mundo!!!".format(usuario))```. Como é que o cara vai voltar a limpar o mundo se ele se suicidou kkk.

Comment: Já consertou? Basicamente crie uma variável `suicidio` de valor `False` , quando for suicídio, logo antes do break mude este valor para `True`. No final você adiciona `if suicidio: [...] else: [...]`

Comment: Mas antes leia o comentário de @IcaroMartins. A primeira observação  é  interessante.

Answer (score 3):

O código estava quase certo.

A condição `if morte == '':` não funcionava porque estava com espaço duplo.

Removi a conversão do `input` porque o retorno já é uma `string`.

Adicionei o `while` para fazer o loop sempre que o usuário digitar `s` indiferente se estiver em caixa alta porque o método `lower` converterá para caixa baixa.

O método `title` coloca o primeiro caractere em maiúsculo .

```
resposta = 's'

while resposta.lower() == 's':

    usuario = input("\nDigite o nome do usuário do caderno: ")

    print("Bem vindo ao Death Note {}".format(usuario.title()))
    print("\nDeseja matar alguém? ")

    resposta = input("S - Sim | N - Não: ")

    if resposta.lower() == 's':

        nome = input("\nDigite o nome da vítima: ")
        morte = input("Digite a causa da morte: ")

        if morte == '':
            print ("\nO nome da vítima é {}".format(nome.title()))
            print ("E morreu de uma parada cardíaca!")
        else:
            print ("\nO nome da vítima é {}".format(nome.title()))
            print ("Causa da morte: {}".format(morte))

print ("\n{} volte quando quiser para limpar o mundo!!!".format(usuario.title())
```

Mantive o primeiro código para que você possa comparar as alterações que implementei com a especificação da sua "observação 2".

Segue a nova versão:

```
resposta = 's'

while resposta.lower() == 's':

    usuario = input("\nDigite o nome do usuário do caderno: ")

    print("Bem vindo ao Death Note {}".format(usuario.title()))
    print("\nDeseja matar alguém? ")

    resposta = input("S - Sim | N - Não: ")

    if resposta.lower() == 's':

        nome = input("\nDigite o nome da vítima: ")
        morte = input("Digite a causa da morte: ")

        if morte == '' and nome != usuario:
            print ("\nO nome da vítima é {}".format(nome.title()))
            print ("E morreu de uma parada cardíaca!")

        elif morte != '' and nome != usuario:
            print ("\nO nome da vítima é {}".format(nome.title()))
            print ("Causa da morte: {}".format(morte))

        elif nome == usuario:
            print ("\n{} você digitou seu próprio nome no Death Note!".format(nome.title()))
            break

        else:
            print ("\n{} volte quando quiser para limpar o mundo!!!".format(usuario.title()))
```

Comment: Ei cara eu editei a pergunta que surgiu uma implementação da minha que surgiu um imprevisto ai

Comment: Alex, compare os dois códigos na minha resposta. A mudança esta nas condições dos comandos "if" e na adição do "break" no de suicídio.